# How to do a nested query within mongodb python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am new to mongodb, and having some trouble writing the correct query.

I am trying to find all documents that have missing high or low prices for stocks with high liquidity.

Here is a document in a collection:

```
{
  "ta_id": {
    "$oid": "63abc4e42970e669a8011c51"
  },
  "dint": 20221223,
  "Open": 0,
  "High": 0,
  "Low": 0,
  "Close": 0,
  "Volume": 0,
}
```

Here is my desired output if I was writing the query in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM collection
WHERE ta_id ON(
SELECT ta_id, AVG(close*volume) AS avg_usd_volume FROM collection
WHERE dint > 20221201
GROUP BY ta_id
HAVING avg_usd_volume >= 10000000)
WHERE High = 0 OR Low = 0 OR Open = 0
```

This is where I am at so far, but I can't figure out how to do a nested query.

```
    results = adjPrices.aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                "dint": {"$gte": 20221201},
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id" : "$ta_id",
                "avg_usd_vol" : {"$avg": {"$multiply": ["$Volume", "$Close"]}}
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                 "avg_usd_vol" : {"$gte": 10000000}
             }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0, 
                "ta_id": "$_id", 
            }
        },
    ])
```

I tried messing with $lookup but that doesn't seem to be working either.
I would really appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is really you want but maybe it can helps you:

The first part (from `$match` to `$project` is as you have), but the `$lookup` can be like this:

Generate a pipeline where you use current `ta_id` and do a "join" where:

1. Your current `ta_id` is the same as the joined table (i.e. you are using the same document).
2. Generate an `$or` structure to accomplish `WHERE High = 0 OR Low = 0 OR Open = 0`.

And optional part is `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot` to get the output at the root level and not in a field called `matching_docs`.

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {ta_id: "$ta_id"},
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {$eq: ["$ta_id","$$ta_id"]},
                {
                  $or: [
                    {$eq: ["$High",0]},
                    {$eq: ["$Low",0]},
                    {$eq: ["$Open",0]}
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "matching_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$matching_docs"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$matching_docs"
    }
  }
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wMWQ-QA0vh6)